R: bioclim tile function is giving me tons of values of bioclimatic variables for specific coordinate point from worldclim
I simply want the data on the 19 bioclimatic variables in worldclim for specific coordinate point. But when doing the below I get tons of values but do not know what they represent. I would like to get only one value representing the geographical coordinates I'm interested in. so what does all these data points represent and what do I need to do to get only one value per bio variable per geographical point?
WCbio<-worldclim_tile(var = "bio", lon = 20.348942, lat = 63.806098, version="2.1", path = "tempdir()")

BioData<-as.data.frame(WCbio)

View(BioData)

then when looking into BioData tons of values per bioclimatic variable are shown like below
> BioData
        tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_1 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_2 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_3 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_4 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_5 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_6 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_7
3325032               0.000000             0.00000000                0.00000                    195                     21                     10               21.28197
3994852              -5.970833             1.41666663              -11.76667                    241                     26                     12               21.54257
3994853              -5.970833             1.41666663              -11.76667                    241                     26                     12               21.54257
3994866              -5.983333             1.39999998              -11.78333                    250                     26                     12               22.33870
3994867              -5.983333             1.39999998              -11.78333                    250                     26                     12               22.33870
3994868              -6.945833             0.28333333              -12.70000                    300                     32                     15               21.94178
3994870              -6.950000             0.28333333              -12.71667                    301                     32                     15               22.20264
3994871              -6.941667             0.28333333              -12.70000                    301                     32                     15               22.20264
3998465              -5.979167             1.39999998              -11.78333                    248                     26                     12               22.03230


I've edited your code so it formats nicely, but can you edit the question and say which package you get the worldclim_tile function from?

The worldclim_tile function from the geodata package returns an entire tile of climate info, in 19 layers of 3600x3600 pixels. If you plot(WCbio) you'll see it.
To get the values at a point once you have a tile that covers that point, create a 2 column matrix and use extract:
> lon = 20.348942 ; lat = 63.806098
> extract(WCbio,matrix(c(lon,lat), ncol=2))
  tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_1 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_2 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_3
1                 3.0375                   13.9              -6.716667
  tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_4 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_5 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_6
1                    636                     73                     34
  tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_7 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_8 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_9
1               27.59197                    207                    108
  tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_10 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_11 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_12
1                     185                     132                7.491666
  tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_13 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_14 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_15
1                24.24487                834.8928                    19.7
  tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_16 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_17 tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_18
1                   -11.2                    30.9                     8.7
  tile_7_wc2.1_30s_bio_19
1                    -3.3

The meaning of these variables is given here: https://worldclim.org/data/bioclim.html

Wow thanks! That helped clarify things and what you suggested worked like a charm! Much appreciated Spacedman! Helped me get over a big hurdle even if it might have been a small problem.
